# API sobre ReportLab con Django

Tags: python, django, reportlab

Bueno, tengo esta duda porque no he encontrado buena documentación al respecto, hay una duda concreta por el momento y es con las imágenes.

```
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.lib.units import cm
from reportlab.lib.enums import TA_JUSTIFY, TA_CENTER
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter, landscape
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet, ParagraphStyle
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph, Spacer, Table, TableStyle, Image
...
    #Logo
    url_logo = EmpresaImagenes.objects.get(id=1).logo
    if url_logo!='':
        im = Image(url_logo, 3*cm, 3*cm)
        im.hAlign ='RIGHT'
        Story.append(im)
```

porque si dejo sólo `Image(url_logo)` la imagen pasa del tamaño real, si pongo `Image(url_logo, 3*cm, 3*cm)` se ajusta a 3cm x 3cm, pero y si sólo quiero ajustar el alto de la imagen y que el ancho sea proporcional?

Me gustaría saber si alguno conoce también un API, guía, tutorial o similar (o varios) que esté(n) bastante completos sobre ReportLab? (en inglés o español)

Es que estoy aprendiendo y necesito hacer varias cosas con ReportLab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Según la definición del `Image`:

> Image(filename, width=None, height=None)

Por lo tanto, es posible que consigas lo que quieres haciendo esto:

```
imagen = Image(url_logo, height=3*cm)
```

Incluso si quieres ser mas curiosa, puedes instalar [`ipython`](http://ipython.org/) y ver como es que se crea una instancia de `Image`:

```
$ ipython
IPython 3.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: from reportlab.platypus import Image

In [2]: Image??
...
```

Podrás notar la definición del método `__init__`:

```
 def __init__(self, filename, width=None, height=None, kind='direct',
              mask="auto", lazy=1, hAlign='CENTER'):
```

Incluso podrías pasarle el atributo `hAlign` al instanciar la imagen:

```
imagen = Image(url_logo, height=3*cm, hAlign='RIGHT')
```

Si me preguntas, yo siempre consulto la [documentación oficial](http://www.reportlab.com/documentation/) de ReportLab y la [Guía de Usuario](http://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf)